# How to add class to seleted checkbox others removed active

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three checkboxes. I want to add class to parent `li` only for selected  checkbox. Other I want to remove class name active or add closed.

**HTML**

```
  <ul>
    <li class="active">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" class="level"/>
          <label>test1</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="closed">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" class="level"/>
          <label>test2</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="closed">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <input type="checkbox" class="level"/>
          <label>test3</label>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.level').on('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).attr('checked')) {
        $(this).closest('ul').parent().addClass('active');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('ul').parent().removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

Comment: no need radio. I want to use only checkbox.

Comment: I want to use only checkbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use [toggleClass](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass)

```js
$('.level').on('click', function(e) {
  var $ul = $(this).closest('ul').parent();
  $ul.toggleClass('active', this.checked);
  $ul.toggleClass('closed', !this.checked);
  if (this.checked) {
    $('.level').not(this).prop('checked', false).closest('ul').parent().removeClass('active').addClass('closed');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: green;
}
.closed {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="closed">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="level" />
        <label>test1</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="closed">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="level" />
        <label>test2</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="np closed">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="level" />
        <label>test3</label>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @user1175112 sorry... what is your requirement

Comment: I want to check only one chckbox others unchecked outof three

Comment: @user1175112 so if you check 1 checkbox, previous selected one has to be unchecked? - why don't you use radio box instead

Comment: can u send by a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

**ToggleClass** is definitely what you want, however if you hook up the event listener properly you won't need to traverse the dom to find the parent list item either.

Instead you can use the **delegateTarget**:

```js
// note i've added a 'top' class to the main <ul>
$('ul.top > li').on('change', 'input', function (e) {

  // select the top-level <li>
  $(e.delegateTarget)
  
  // toggle the active/closed class based on the 'checked' state of the input
  .toggleClass('active', this.checked).toggleClass('closed', !this.checked);
  
});
```

```css
.top li:before { content: attr(class); } .active { font-weight: bold; color: green; } .closed { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="top"><li class="active"><ul><li><input type="checkbox" class="level" checked /><label>test1</label></li></ul></li><li class="closed"><ul><li><input type="checkbox" class="level" /><label>test2</label></li></ul></li><li class="closed"><ul><li><input type="checkbox" class="level" /><label>test3</label></li></ul></li></ul>
```